# Trying to understand what the conic section elements are

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If possible, could someone explain the major elements of the conic sections?  By that I mean

- focus
- directrix
- principal axis
- vertex
- eccentricity
- and any other features of a conic section that are important.

My precalculus textbook is unclear.

> [And here is where I (OP) should put what I *do* know] 
>   <sup>$\sim$ a   friendly message from a person who edited this question</sup>

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please be somewhat clearer. Give us your definitions so we can explain them to you. In this way, we can help you in the best way possible :)

Answer (score 2):

### Ellipse

Take two points $F_1$ and $F_2$ in the plane and fix a number $L$ that's bigger than the distance between the two points.  Then an ellipse is is the set of points $P$ such that the distance from $F_1$ to $P$ plus the distance from $F_2$ to $P$ is $L$.

[image]

$F_1$ and $F_2$ are called the foci of the ellipse.  Besides $L$, we define a few other useful numbers associated with ellipses.

[image]

Notice that in general ellipses has a longer direction (horizontal in the image above) and a shorter direction (vertical).

- The line segment through the center of the ellipse to each of the furthest points is called the **major axis**.  Half of this (the line segment from the center to just one of the furthest points) is a **semi-major axis**.
- The other axis is the **minor axis** and it has two **semi-minor axes**, as well.
- Those two further points on the ends of the major axis are called the **vertices** (plural of vertex) and the end points of the minor axis are called the **co-vertices** (plural of co-vertex).
- The two points we used to draw our ellipse are called the **foci** (plural of focus).
- The **focal distance** is the distance from the center to one of the foci.
- The **eccentricity** describes how elongated the ellipse is.  It is calculated as the focal length divided by the length of the semi-major axis.  So it is the fraction of the length of the semi-major axis that the focal length takes up (think percentage but in decimal form).

  - The smallest the eccentricity can be is $0$.The is when the foci are *right at the center*.  In this case you just get a circle.
  - Going the other way, as the focal length gets closer and closer to the length of the semi-major axis -- i.e., the eccentricity gets closer to $1$ -- the less circular and more elongated the ellipse looks.

### Parabola

Estimated release date: 12/15/2017.

### Hyperbola

Plans are to release it as DLC sometime next year.